# How is the same reference binding different objects?

Tags: c++, c++11

We know that,once we bind an object to a reference,we cannot rebind another object to that reference.
But in the below range `for` statement ,the same reference binds to different objects or elements sequentially.

```
std::string s;
for(auto &i:s)
{/*each character is referred sequentially*/
}
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I recommend e.g. [this range-for reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Pay special mind to the implementation details shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the same reference binds to different objects

It is **not** the same reference. The reference `i` (not the object it points to) is being destroyed and constructed again on each iteration of the loop, so they are different references. See also David's comment below.

Comment: No different from `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { int& j = func(i); ... }`. Each iteration of the loop, `j` is a brand new reference.

Answer (score 0):

> But in the below range for statement ,the same reference binds to different objects or elements sequentially.

No it doesn't.

Look at this:

```
void foo()
{
   int x = 1;
}

void bar()
{
   int x = 2;
}
```

The two `x`s are different variables, right?

The same is true of `i` in your loop. That is simply how it is defined to work. You are not writing an old-fashioned `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)` here.